# Altering the UIButton behaviour by subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to create a check box button which will be used throughout my application at many places. The one basic behaviour I wanted for this button was to alternatively changed its state when the button was tapped. So I subclassed this button and wrote the following class. Basically it just adds one extra target method to button in the -`awakeFromNib` function.

```
//
//  CheckBoxButton.h
//  CheckBoxButton
//
//  Created by Ankit Srivastava on 11/07/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CheckBoxButton : UIButton

@end
```

here is the .m

```
/
//  CheckBoxButton.m
//  CheckBoxButton
//
//  Created by Ankit Srivastava on 11/07/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CheckBoxButton.h"

@implementation CheckBoxButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(alterState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void) alterState:(UIButton*)sender {
    [self setSelected:!self.isSelected];
}

@end
```

Now I add the button via xib and just change its base class to `CheckBoxButton`.
Every thing works fine but I have heard that `UIButton` should not be subclassed but I couldn't find any documented proof and also I am just adding a method to the button to change its state. So my question is whether this approach is OK..?

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: You are better off subclassing `UIControl`, and if you use them in a `NIB` file the `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` is called and here you can add the target.

Answer (score 0):

I've subclassed UIButton several times. It's a class cluster so there are potential issues when doing so, but I have yet to run into any show stoppers.